# How to use boost asio to async_connect every ten seconds?

Tags: c++, boost, asio

I want to use boost asio to create a tcp client, and async_connect to a server every ten second until successful. Do you give me an example? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [boost::asio::deadline_timer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/deadline_timer.html) to measure time until the next connection attempt.

1. Call async_connect, pass handler, e.g. `handle_connect`
2. If `handle_connect` states that any error has occured, use a deadline_timer to measure 10 seconds before the next connection attempt.